# Beautiful Soup - Selecting Class has Unexpected Results

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am new to programming and have been learning **Python** through web scraping. What I am trying to do is capture the below line from the site listed in my URL:

`<a class="" href="https://www.adweek.com?paged=776%3Fs%3Dinterpublic&amp;orderby=date&amp;s=interpublic">776</a>`, but I cannot seem to get there. It only returns the first line of pagination information and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.adweek.com/?s=interpublic&orderby=date'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
k =soup.find_all('div', {'class':'pagination-centered'})
```

Returns only --

```
[<div class="pagination-centered"><ul class="pagination">
 <li><span aria-current="page" class="current">1</span></li></ul></div>]
```

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: please post your desired output?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to completely load before you do a query?  That div probably gets filled out with javascript later

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to get to the 776 number located in the first bit of code, but it should all be wrapped in the pagination section. However, I cannot seem to get anything more than the first section in the pagination area except the Next part. At the end of the day I want the number 776.

Comment: I can see it in the variable, but cannot seem to access it.

Comment: Where do you see it?  In the output of soup or by inspecting the HTML code in a browser?

Comment: I see it in my soup object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pagination using `a[href*="paged="]` css selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.adweek.com/?s=interpublic&orderby=date'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

# print text and href
pagination = soup.select('a[href*="paged="]')
for p in pagination:
    print(p.text.strip(), p.get('href'))
```

"Next" has same url as first link, you can use `set` to get only unique href. :

```
pagination = {p['href'] for p in soup.select('a[href*="paged="]')}
```

You can get last page number and iterate by changing parameter `paged` in the url until the last page.

Page source without JavaScript:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! While I don't understand what you did, it certainly did the trick.